# How can I apply the Lagrange multipliers method for several constrains?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I think I am not understanding some key steps to apply the LM method when we have several constrains. For instance, if we had to find the global extrema of a function $f(x,y,z)$ in a set *M* defined by the constrains $g_1(x,y,z)$  and $g_2(x,y,z)$, and an additional condition, say $ g_3 =y\le0$, I would follow these steps:

1. Check the interior of *M* for critical points that are in the interior (through the gradient of *f*)
2. Apply Lagrange to $g_1$
3. Apply Lagrange to $g_2$
4. Apply Lagrange to $g_3$
5. Apply Lagrange to the intersections
     $$g_{1} \cap g_{2} \cap g_{3}$$
   $$g_{1} \cap g_{2}$$$$g_{1} \cap g_{3}$$$$g_{2} \cap g_{3}$$
6. Select the maximum and minimum by computing the values of *f* at the points.

However, sometimes my professor just does Steps 1, 5A; while other times he goes through every step.

I am really confused.

All help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your set $M$ is defined by the constraints
$$
 g_1 (x,y,z) \leq0 \qquad
 g_2 (x,y,z) \leq0 
$$

Then we can find a higher dimensional function
$$
 g(x,y,z) = (g_1(x,y,z),g_2(x,y,z))
$$

and then $M$ is defined by the constraint
$$
 g(x,y,z) \leq0,
$$
so we have just one (although higher-dimensional) function.

That is why it is very often only considered, where the set is only defined by one inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still am confused about how to know when to apply which intersections. Will I be safe by applying all of them?